# Image displaying next to the list

Tags: html, css

I have some code that has the property `display-inline`. Due to this it displays the list horizontally. Now, I placed an image in my code and it appeared after the list. I wanted the image to be displayed below the list so I placed the list into a div but still its getting displayed next to the list. Here is the code,

```
<ul id="list-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--navigation div ends-->
<!--<div>-->
<img src="Book_Cover-465x540.png" />
```

CSS of list-nav:

```
ul#list-nav {
margin:40px;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
width:525px;
}
ul#list-nav li {
display:inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px 0;
width:100px;
background:#000000;
color:#eee;
float:left;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
text-align:center;
border-left:15px solid #fff;
}
```

Please help out. Thanks

Comment: add style="clear:both;" to your image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
<div>
<ul id="list-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--navigation div ends-->
<!--<div>-->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<img src="Book_Cover-465x540.png" />
```

Comment: There's no need to clear anything, just remove unnecessary flots. But if one really needs to do clearfix, there's a better way: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from `a`.
Also: what the heck is `border-left:15px solid #fff;`, didn't you mean left margin?

Comment: Yes. Thats the same thing. Actually used a snippet from a tutorial.

Comment: Are you saying that margin and border are the same thing? Really?

Comment: No, they're not. Certainly they're not. Trust me.

Comment: Your solution is affecting the list to be displayed properly.